# Conditional validation in Angular 4

Tags: angular

i have a form with multiple textbox and check box controls .. i need to put conditional validation for that in angular 4.

**when i checked a checkbox based on that some text box's enabled ..so when i checked a check box i need to put required validation's for enabled text box's **.

this is my code ..

```
<form #fm="ngForm" id="MachineshopTab" (ngSubmit)="fm.form.valid && 
    MachineSave(fm.value,'Continue')">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="Ringname">Tool Ring Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input #Ringname="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="machineshop.Ringname" type="text" class="form-control form-control-default" placeholder="Tool Ring 
    Name" (change)="ToolRingNameChange(fm.value)" id="Toolringtext" name="Ringname" [style.border-color]="(fm.submitted &&  
    !Ringname.valid)==true?'#d9534f':'#75777c'">
                        <div class="text text-danger col-sm-12 p-0" *ngIf="fm.submitted && 
    !Ringname.valid">Device Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input id="chkSpacer" class="border-checkbox depart" #Spacer="ngModel" name="Spacer" [(ngModel)]="machineshop.Spacer" type="checkbox" value="Spacer">

            <label class="border-checkbox-label" for="chkSpacer">Spacer</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="divjig" [hidden]="!machineshop.Jig">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class=" col-form-label title-head" for="Jig">Jig</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                <div class="form-group row">

                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input #Jigquantity="ngModel" *ngIf="Spacer.valid==true?'required':''" [(ngModel)]="machineshop.Jigquantity" type="text" class="form-control form-
    control-default" placeholder="Quantity" name="Jigquantity">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="continue btn btn-warning">Continue
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where is your validator implementation and your component class?

Comment: thanks for replay ...i have used Template driven Forms..

Comment: when i click on submit button ngsubmit fires the validation based on form is valid or not

Comment: In above code i have used these lines *ngIf="Spacer.valid==true?'required':''" .. here required  validation not working

Comment: Please any one can help me

Comment: Hi everyone please help me how to put conditionally validation in angular 4 for above situation..I'm really waiting for your ans.thanks